# Organic-Groups multisite architecture

Tags: 7, organic-groups, nodes, uri

I have a task to build a series of websites all related to the same core business.

Initially, I was going to build each one as a separate website.
Later however, I was told the sites have to be able to share content which changed my plans.

Going by the logic that the easiest way to build multiple Drupal websites which share content is to build one site and make it work and appear as many.

So, I decided to build the site in [Organic Groups](https://drupal.org/project/OG) but I have the following functionality challenges.

1. How can I direct unique URLs to individual Groups on my site. I:E configuring **www.mysite.co.uk** to visit Group#1 and **www.mysite.com** to visit Group#2 etc
2. Is there a way to create content on the Drupal site which can optionally be shared/posted to one or more of my Groups? **The idea is to create content on the primary 'website' and the same content displays in the Groups/'sub-sites'**.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think that the module [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) would meet your needs more than Organic Groups would. A friend of mine recently created a site matching exactly your criteria.

> Module Package includes:
>
> Domain Alias 6.x.2 and higher only by bforchhammer. Allows you to
>   specify subdomain aliases and domain name patterns for domain entries
>   so that multiple hostnames are matched on a single domain entry.
>
> Domain Configuration -- Allows you to change select system variables
>   for each subdomain, such as offline status, footer message and default
>   home page.
>
> Domain Content -- Provides a content administration page for each
>   subdomain, so that affiliate editors can administer content for their
>   section of the site.
>
> Domain Navigation -- Supplies a navigation block with three themes.
>   Creates menu items for each subdomain, suitable for using as primary
>   or secondary links.
>
> Domain Path -- Enables custom path aliases per domain.
>
> Domain Prefix -- Provides a user interface for enabling select
>   database table prefixing for use with subdomains. The Drupal 5 version
>   is not fully functional on pgSQL, but Drupal 6 version is.
>
> Domain Settings -- Exposes domain-sensitive variable settings to most
>   configuration forms. Requires Domain Conf.
>
> Domain Source -- Allows editors to set a primary source domain when
>   links are written to content from other domains.
>
> Domain Strict -- Forces users to be members of domains in order to
>   view content. This is a sample extension module that uses the API.
>
> Domain Theme -- Allows separate themes, theme settings and colors for
>   each subdomain.
>
> Domain User -- Allows for the automatic creation of subdomains for
>   registered users.
>
> Domain Views by mrichar1 and nonsie -- Provides Views integration for
>   Views 5.x.1 and 6.x.2 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I am reviewing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Spaces + PURL + Organic Groups, similar to OpenScholar Distribution. But the development for spaces module is almost stalled. If you are like me and want to go with that route then be prepared to write a lot of custom code.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7: Domain access would make more sense and you could share content between sites as well as views, themes, styles, modules.

In 8 Group (not organic groups) uses a domain access feature as well (a separate module).

You mentioned multisite in the title which is another option (share code, separate dbs).